# Converting DateTime to Datetime? (null-coalescing?)

Tags: c#, mysql

I've got a tiny problem. In my database my DateTime(?) has an auto property of null. I'm using the class RentalDTO() which has the property of DateTime? returnDate. Something like this:

```
    public class RentalDTO
    {
        public DateTime? ReturnDate { get; set; }

        public RentalDTO()
        {

        }
        public RentalDTO(DateTime? returnDate)
        {
            ReturnDate = returnDate;
        }
```

The question. How do I use my sql reader to convert my database DateTime to my RentalDTO DateTime?

```
public RentalDTO RentalDTOFromMySqlDataReader(MySqlDataReader reader)
        {
            RentalDTO rental = new RentalDTO(
                Convert.ToDateTime(reader["returndate"]) // How to convert this? Convert.ToDateTime Does not work
                );

            return rental;
        }
```

Convert.ToDateTime does not work. It gives an error.

Comment: Why do you not tell us, what reader["returndate"] actually is, it is not a valid Datetime

Comment: "Convert.ToDateTime Does not work" doesn't really tell us anything. "It gives an error" - so what is the error? When writing a Stack Overflow question, please try to anticipate any obvious requests for more information. Imagine you were trying to help someone, and they said their code gives an error. Isn't your obvious first question "What's the error"?

Comment: `reader.GetDateTime("returndate")` would be a likely first solution...

Comment: @JonSkeet I'll remember it for my next post, thanks for the tip.

Comment: You don't need to wait for the next post - you can edit *this* question to vastly improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the `reader["returndate"]` is `null` or not. then cast the value to a `Nullable` `Datetime`

```cs
public RentalDTO RentalDTOFromMySqlDataReader(MySqlDataReader reader)
{
    DateTime? dateTime = string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader["returndate"]) ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.Parse(reader["returndate"]);
    RentalDTO rental = new RentalDTO(dateTime);
    return rental;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm very sorry, i would type this in comment but i'm not allowed to write comments yet, but my wild guess would be try using `DateTime.TryParse();` and specify the format of date, it is possible string is in an invalid format, isnt it ? Also it would handle null.